# Difference between two correlations measure methods

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I am trying to measure the correlation between two binary categorical variables.
I tried in two ways.

1. Use the chi-square test for independence of two-way table. The p-value as the correlation.
2. Treat them as numerical variables with value of 0/1. Calculate the correlation between them.

The results are so different, the first gives 9.5e(-31) and the second gives around 0.3.

How to interpret these two correlations and why the difference can be so large?

Comment: Are you using the p-value to determine the strength of correlation? I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: The second is a phi coefficient and is fine. But what makes you believe that the p-value from the chi-square test can be interpreted as a correlation?

Comment: @Vishal I think since the smaller P-value is, the less likely two variables are independent. That's very similar to a measure of strength of correlation. Not sure it makes sense.

Comment: @Wolfgang That's my doubt here also. Can p-value of the A/B test here give the measure to strength of correlation. Why or why not?

Comment: The p-value depends also upon sample size, and not only upon the correlation

Answer (score 1):

The p-value from the chi-squared test cannot in any way be interpreted as a correlation. There are at least two reasons:

- The p-value will depend on sample size, and not only on strength of association or correlation. With a given non-null association (measure of dependence) when the sample size grows, the p-value will tend to be lower.
- When the correlation/association *increases*, the p-value will tend to *decrease*. So for a given sample size, association/correlation will be antimonotonic with p-value.

So to summarize: the p-value measures *strength of evidence*, not *strength of association/correlation*.

Comment: There is at least a third fundamental reason: As the p-value can never be negative it cannot -- unlike a correlation and several measures of association -- carry information on direction of relationship.